# Error installing Pentaho CTools

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I am trying to install the [CTools](http://community.pentaho.com/ctools/) into *biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable* through [ctools-installer](https://github.com/pmalves/ctools-installer), but it always fails the same way. I cd into the *biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable*, and there, I run, let's say, to install CDF:

```
sh /home/andy/ctools-installer.sh -s pentaho-solutions -w tomcat/webapps/pentaho -c cdf -y
```

it downloads cdf, but when it tries to install, shows this:

```
unzip: cannot find or open .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip, .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip.zip or .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip.ZIP.
```

The full trace is here:

```
andy@GDAI-Laptop ~/biserver-ce $ sh /home/andy/ctools-installer.sh -s pentaho-solutions -w tomcat/webapps/pentaho -c cdf -y
/home/andy/ctools-installer.sh: 199: /home/andy/ctools-installer.sh: shopt: not found

Downloading files

Downloading CDF...--2017-08-25 11:45:12--  http://ctools.pentaho.com/files/cdf/15.10.26/4.x/dist.zip    
    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.    
Done    
Installing files    
unzip:  cannot find or open .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip, .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip.zip or .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-+([0-9.]).zip.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
unzip:  cannot find or open .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-samples-+([0-9.])*zip, .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-samples-+([0-9.])*zip.zip or .tmp/dist/pentaho-cdf-samples-+([0-9.])*zip.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
cleanup

Done!
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Problem solved! The issue was I was running the script with **sh**, and it was meant to be run with **bash**, so *shopt* didn't work.